# Function not running, but rather being inserted as text

Tags: vim

I have this bit of magic in `.vimrc`:

```
inoremap <Tab> <c-r>=InsertTabWrapper()<Return>
function! InsertTabWrapper()
    let col = col('.') - 1
    if !col || getline('.')[col - 1] !~ '\k' 
        return "\<tab>"
    else    
        return "\<c-p>"
    endif   
endfunction
```

This works fine on all systems that I use it (insert Tab at beginning of line, autocomplete otherwise), however on one system running VIM v7.0.237 the actual text `InsertTabWrapper()` is inserted into the file instead of running the function. Casual googling leads me to believe that any VIM 7.x version should support function calls like this. So what else might be the issue?

Comment: Does `<C-r>=1+2<CR>` work?

Comment: Instead of `<Return>`, could you try `<CR>`, which executes what was before it. Also try what @romainl said.

Comment: Does the output of "`:set cpo?`" (with the `?` as part of the command) include "`<`" and/or "`k`"?

Comment: Thanks. Even `<C-r>=1+2<CR>` doesn't work (it prints `1+2` to the file). Note that upon pressing `<C-r>` I do see the expected `"` character to let me know that I've pressed `<C-r>`, but upon pressing `=` it disappears and the following characters are printed to the file.

Comment: @Heptite: `cpoptions=aABceFs`. I'll google exactly what that means. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like the expression register is not available. Do you have `+eval` in `$ vim --version | grep eval`? What about `:set compatible?`?

Comment: Thanks, romainl, there is no eval support! I'll have a talk with the server admin. Could you post your comment as an answer so that I could accept it? Thanks.

Comment: @romainl: Please post your comment as an answer, so that I could accept it. You helped me locate the root of the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Comment answerized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So…

The fact that Vim couldn't evaluate an expression as simple as `1+2` suggested that it's unable to use "expressions" as a whole. AFAIK, the only reason for that would be that Vim is not built with the `+eval` feature.

That's why I asked you to check the presence of `+eval` in `$ vim --version | grep eval`.